# Find an another "special" array in a non-empty array (slice) using interface

Tags: arrays, go, recursion

I want to write a function that takes in a "special" array and returns its product sum in Golang.(The more nested, the multiplier increases by 1)

Here is one of the solutions using interface but I am not sure why this code works. I understand the general logic but not sure why 'interface' can distinguish if current element is a type of "special" array. (contains slice).

Since we are passing an array with type of SpecialArray interface, all of ranged elements could be a type of SpecialArray so it looks like there is no chance to go into else statement. Is there anything like built-in "SpecialArray" interface in Golang?

Here is the example of input value and output.
`array = [5, 2, [7, -1], 3, [6, [-13, 8], 4]] => output = 12 // 5 + 2 + 2 *( 7 -1) +3 + 2 * (6 + 3 * (-13 +8) + 4)`

```
package main

type SpecialArray []interface{}

func ProductSum(array []interface{}) int {
    return helper(array, 1)
}

func helper(array SpecialArray, multiplier int) int {
    sum := 0
    // loop passed array
    for _, element := range array {
        if cast, ok := element.(SpecialArray); ok {
            sum += helper(cast, multiplier + 1)
        } else if cast, ok := element.(int); ok {
            sum += cast
        }
    }
    return sum * multiplier
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for _, element := range array {
```

Gets individual elements from what is being considered

```
if cast, ok := element.(SpecialArray); ok {
```

This means if the current element is a "SpecialArray" (or []interface) then do something - and that something is to recursively call the helper function

```
} else if cast, ok := element.(int); ok {
```

This means the array has got to the integers inside the array so it's ok to add them up

See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions in the Go language spec